# Flutter - Want to show camera Tabbarview in full screen

Tags: flutter, dart, tabbar

I am building WhatsApp clone for demo. I want to hide AppBar and Tabbar when I click on Camera tab and I want CameraScreen in full screen. I hope, I could made very clear. I have also included whole code of the CameraScreen page thus you can understand(just edited to add whole code).
Sorry for uploading code late.
Thank you in advance.

Here is scree shot:[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImKNp.jpg)

```
class _CameraScreenState extends State<CameraScreen> {
  CameraController? _cameraController;
  // bool _isvideoRecording = false;

  Future<void>? cameravalue;
  bool isrecording = false;
  String videopath = '';
  XFile? videorecording;
  bool flash = false;
  bool isCameraFront = false;
  double trasform = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _cameraController = CameraController(camera![0], ResolutionPreset.high);
    cameravalue = _cameraController!.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    _cameraController!.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        FutureBuilder(
          future: cameravalue,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return CameraPreview(_cameraController!);
            } else {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 5,
              bottom: 5,
            ),
            color: Colors.black,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          flash = !flash;
                        });
                        flash
                            ? _cameraController!.setFlashMode(FlashMode.torch)
                            : _cameraController!.setFlashMode(FlashMode.off);
                      },
                      icon: Icon(
                        flash ? Icons.flash_on : Icons.flash_off,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 28,
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onLongPress: () async {
                        await _cameraController!.startVideoRecording();
                        setState(() {
                          isrecording = true;
                        });
                      },
                      onLongPressUp: () async {
                        XFile videopath =
                            await _cameraController!.stopVideoRecording();
                        setState(() {
                          isrecording = false;
                        });
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (builder) => VideoView(
                                      path: videopath.path,
                                    )));                      
},
                      onTap: () {
                        if (!isrecording) {
                          takePhoto(context);
                        }
                      },
                      child: isrecording
                          ? const Icon(
                              Icons.radio_button_on,
                              color: Colors.red,
                              size: 80,
                            )
                          : const Icon(
                              Icons.panorama_fish_eye,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 70,
                            ),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        setState(() {
                          isCameraFront = !isCameraFront;
                          trasform = trasform + pi;
                        });
                        int cameraPos = isCameraFront ? 0 : 1;
                        _cameraController = CameraController(
                            camera![cameraPos], ResolutionPreset.high);
                        cameravalue = _cameraController!.initialize();
                      },
                      icon: Transform.rotate(
                        angle: trasform,
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.flip_camera_ios,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 4,
                ),
                const Text(
                  'Hold for Video, tap for photo',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  void takePhoto(BuildContext context) async {
    final path =
        join((await getTemporaryDirectory()).path, "${DateTime.now()}.png");
    XFile picture = await _cameraController!.takePicture();
    picture.saveTo(path);
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => CameraView(
          path: path,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have just added code

Comment: Can u add more code, probably full file code from your Scalfold widget

Comment: @manhtuan21 please check. I have updated whole code

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this features by doing the following simple steps. There will be another possible solutions.

First of all, create a new route ( new widget ) that contains camera view in fullscreen.

When you tap the camera tab, go to that route with fade-in or scale animation with faster duration that will make UI more realistic.